# do user_scans and no user_seeks mean the index is useless?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm digging into **sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats** and finding that a number of our indexes are used exclusively in user_scans, not user_seeks.  Does this imply that the index is useless and should be redesigned?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not useless, but maybe sub-optimal.  Scanning a 10 MB index is a hell of a lot faster than scanning a 1 GB table, though a seek would be even better.  Can you tell us more about the indices?  How are the tables being used?

Comment: Great point!  I am just starting to examine a variety of databases we have around here to make some suggestions on where things can be improved - I will be digging deeper... and probably posting more questions.  :)